# Controller on Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible in Wordpress to create a global controller for the requests?

***Example:***
I write www.test.com/lorem/ipsum that is not a resource (it is nothing) and I want to handle this request to create a custom myQuery to WebService.

Thanks for the the answers ahead!

Comment: Check [this](http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/)

Answer (score 0):

We from WordPress call it **Rewrite-Class**. Check out the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite